# JavaScript - adding in ID and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some JS code for a pop-up mobile browser that works as a mobile nav (Links pop up and can be clicked to go places etc.)

However outside buttons (With more JS code) translates the page between English and Chinese does not translate the mobile nav text. I believe this is because this JS code is not importing the unique ID's and 'tr' class from the main HTML file to the mobile nav.

What would I have to do to bring this import over?

See mobile nav JS Code here:

```js
/**
 * Generate an indented list of links from a nav. Meant for use with panel().
 * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
 */
$.fn.navList = function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  $a = $this.find('a'),
    b = [];

  $a.each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
      indent = Math.max(0, $this.parents('li').length - 1),
      href = $this.attr('href'),
      target = $this.attr('target');


    b.push(
      '<a ' +
      'class="link depth tr-' + indent + '"' +
      ((typeof target !== 'undefined' && target != '') ? ' target="' + target + '"' : '') +
      ((typeof href !== 'undefined' && href != '') ? ' href="' + href + '"' : '') +
      '>' +
      '<span class="indent tr-' + indent + '"></span>' +
      $this.text() +
      '</a>'
    );

  });

  return b.join('');

};

/**
 * Panel-ify an element.
 * @param {object} userConfig User config.
 * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
 */
$.fn.panel = function(userConfig) {

  // No elements?
  if (this.length == 0)
    return $this;

  // Multiple elements?
  if (this.length > 1) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
      $(this[i]).panel(userConfig);

    return $this;

  }

  // Vars.
  var $this = $(this),
    $body = $('body'),
    $window = $(window),
    id = $this.attr('id'),
    config;

  // Config.
  config = $.extend({

    // Delay.
    delay: 0,

    // Hide panel on link click.
    hideOnClick: false,

    // Hide panel on escape keypress.
    hideOnEscape: false,

    // Hide panel on swipe.
    hideOnSwipe: false,

    // Reset scroll position on hide.
    resetScroll: false,

    // Reset forms on hide.
    resetForms: false,

    // Side of viewport the panel will appear.
    side: null,

    // Target element for "class".
    target: $this,

    // Class to toggle.
    visibleClass: 'visible'

  }, userConfig);

  // Expand "target" if it's not a jQuery object already.
  if (typeof config.target != 'jQuery')
    config.target = $(config.target);

  // Panel.

  // Methods.
  $this._hide = function(event) {

    // Already hidden? Bail.
    if (!config.target.hasClass(config.visibleClass))
      return;

    // If an event was provided, cancel it.
    if (event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

    }

    // Hide.
    config.target.removeClass(config.visibleClass);

    // Post-hide stuff.
    window.setTimeout(function() {

      // Reset scroll position.
      if (config.resetScroll)
        $this.scrollTop(0);

      // Reset forms.
      if (config.resetForms)
        $this.find('form').each(function() {
          this.reset();
        });

    }, config.delay);

  };



  // Vendor fixes.
  $this
    .css('-ms-overflow-style', '-ms-autohiding-scrollbar')
    .css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling', 'touch');

  // Hide on click.
  if (config.hideOnClick) {

    $this.find('a')
      .css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

    $this
      .on('click', 'a', function(event) {

        var $a = $(this),
          href = $a.attr('href'),
          target = $a.attr('target');


        if (!href || href == '#' || href == '' || href == '#' + id)
          return;

        // Cancel original event.
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Hide panel.
        $this._hide();

        // Redirect to href.
        window.setTimeout(function() {

          if (target == '_blank')
            window.open(href);
          else
            window.location.href = href;

        }, config.delay + 10);

      });

  }

  // Event: Touch stuff.
  $this.on('touchstart', function(event) {

    $this.touchPosX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    $this.touchPosY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;

  })

  $this.on('touchmove', function(event) {

    if ($this.touchPosX === null ||
      $this.touchPosY === null)
      return;

    var diffX = $this.touchPosX - event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
      diffY = $this.touchPosY - event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,
      th = $this.outerHeight(),
      ts = ($this.get(0).scrollHeight - $this.scrollTop());

    // Hide on swipe?
    if (config.hideOnSwipe) {

      var result = false,
        boundary = 20,
        delta = 50;

      switch (config.side) {

        case 'left':
          result = (diffY < boundary && diffY > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffX > delta);
          break;

        case 'right':
          result = (diffY < boundary && diffY > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffX < (-1 * delta));
          break;

        case 'top':
          result = (diffX < boundary && diffX > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffY > delta);
          break;

        case 'bottom':
          result = (diffX < boundary && diffX > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffY < (-1 * delta));
          break;

        default:
          break;

      }

      if (result) {

        $this.touchPosX = null;
        $this.touchPosY = null;
        $this._hide();

        return false;

      }

    }

    // Prevent vertical scrolling past the top or bottom.
    if (($this.scrollTop() < 0 && diffY < 0) ||
      (ts > (th - 2) && ts < (th + 2) && diffY > 0)) {

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

    }

  });

  // Event: Prevent certain events inside the panel from bubbling.
  $this.on('click touchend touchstart touchmove', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Event: Hide panel if a child anchor tag pointing to its ID is clicked.
  $this.on('click', 'a[href="#' + id + '"]', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    config.target.removeClass(config.visibleClass);

  });

  // Body.

  // Event: Hide panel on body click/tap.
  $body.on('click touchend', function(event) {
    $this._hide(event);
  });

  // Event: Toggle.
  $body.on('click', 'a[href="#' + id + '"]', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    config.target.toggleClass(config.visibleClass);

  });

  // Window.

  // Event: Hide on ESC.
  if (config.hideOnEscape)
    $window.on('keydown', function(event) {

      if (event.keyCode == 27)
        $this._hide(event);

    });

  return $this;

};
```

Here is the HTML code with the 'tr' classes and the unique ID's:

```html
<!-- Header -->
<header id="header" class="trans">
  <h1>
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="images/Artboard%201.png" alt="logo" class="logo"> </a>
  </h1>
  <button id="en" class="zonetime2 lang"> English </button>
  <button id="ch" class="zonetime lang"> 中文 </button>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul class="tr">
      <li><a href="index.html" key="home" class="link depth-0 tr">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html" key="about" class="tr">About Us</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="submenu fa-angle-down tr" key="serv">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="SEM.html" key="sem" class="tr">Search Engine Marketing</a></li>
          <li><a href="WebDev.html" key="webdev" class="tr">Website Development </a></li>
          <li><a href="AppDev.html" key="app" class="tr">App Development</a></li>
          <li><a href="Automation.html" key="tbd" class="tr">Technical Business Development</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="ourteam.html" key="ourteam" class="tr">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="button tr" key="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>



  </nav>

</header>
```

Here is the translate JS code as well for reference:

```js
// onclick behavior
$('.lang').click('touchstart', function() {
  var lang = $(this).attr('id'); // obtain language id

  // translate all translatable elements
  $('.tr').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(aLangKeys[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
  });

});

// preparing language file
var aLangKeys = new Array();
aLangKeys['en'] = new Array();
aLangKeys['ch'] = new Array();

aLangKeys['en']['home'] = 'Home';
aLangKeys['en']['about'] = 'About Us';
aLangKeys['en']['serv'] = 'Services';
aLangKeys['en']['sem'] = 'Search Engine Marketing';
aLangKeys['en']['webdev'] = 'Website Development';
aLangKeys['en']['app'] = 'Mobile App Development';
aLangKeys['en']['tbd'] = 'Technical Business Development';
aLangKeys['en']['ourteam'] = 'Our Team';
aLangKeys['en']['contactus'] = 'Contact Us';
aLangKeys['en']['submit'] = 'Send Message';
aLangKeys['en']['reset'] = 'Reset';


aLangKeys['ch']['home'] = '首页';
aLangKeys['ch']['about'] = '关于我们';
aLangKeys['ch']['serv'] = '服务';
aLangKeys['ch']['sem'] = '谷歌与雅虎推广';
aLangKeys['ch']['webdev'] = '品牌网站建设';
aLangKeys['ch']['app'] = 'APP 开发';
aLangKeys['ch']['tbd'] = '加拿大工商业与市场拓展';
aLangKeys['ch']['ourteam'] = '我们的团队';
aLangKeys['ch']['contactus'] = '联络我们';
aLangKeys['ch']['submit'] = '发留言';
aLangKeys['ch']['reset'] = '重新';
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your translation seems to be using the `key` attribute so make sure these are taken into account when cloning the nav structure.

```js
/**
 * Generate an indented list of links from a nav. Meant for use with panel().
 * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
 */
$.fn.navList = function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  $a = $this.find('a'),
    b = [];

  $a.each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
      indent = Math.max(0, $this.parents('li').length - 1),
      href = $this.attr('href'),
      target = $this.attr('target'),
      key = $this.attr('key');


    b.push(
      '<a ' +
      'class="link depth tr-' + indent + '"' +
      ((typeof target !== 'undefined' && target != '') ? ' target="' + target + '"' : '') +
      ((typeof key !== 'undefined' && key != '') ? ' key="' + key + '"' : '') +
      ((typeof href !== 'undefined' && href != '') ? ' href="' + href + '"' : '') +
      '>' +
      '<span class="indent tr-' + indent + '"></span>' +
      $this.text() +
      '</a>'
    );

  });

  return b.join('');

};

/**
 * Panel-ify an element.
 * @param {object} userConfig User config.
 * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
 */
$.fn.panel = function(userConfig) {

  // No elements?
  if (this.length == 0)
    return $this;

  // Multiple elements?
  if (this.length > 1) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
      $(this[i]).panel(userConfig);

    return $this;

  }

  // Vars.
  var $this = $(this),
    $body = $('body'),
    $window = $(window),
    id = $this.attr('id'),
    config;

  // Config.
  config = $.extend({

    // Delay.
    delay: 0,

    // Hide panel on link click.
    hideOnClick: false,

    // Hide panel on escape keypress.
    hideOnEscape: false,

    // Hide panel on swipe.
    hideOnSwipe: false,

    // Reset scroll position on hide.
    resetScroll: false,

    // Reset forms on hide.
    resetForms: false,

    // Side of viewport the panel will appear.
    side: null,

    // Target element for "class".
    target: $this,

    // Class to toggle.
    visibleClass: 'visible'

  }, userConfig);

  // Expand "target" if it's not a jQuery object already.
  if (typeof config.target != 'jQuery')
    config.target = $(config.target);

  // Panel.

  // Methods.
  $this._hide = function(event) {

    // Already hidden? Bail.
    if (!config.target.hasClass(config.visibleClass))
      return;

    // If an event was provided, cancel it.
    if (event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

    }

    // Hide.
    config.target.removeClass(config.visibleClass);

    // Post-hide stuff.
    window.setTimeout(function() {

      // Reset scroll position.
      if (config.resetScroll)
        $this.scrollTop(0);

      // Reset forms.
      if (config.resetForms)
        $this.find('form').each(function() {
          this.reset();
        });

    }, config.delay);

  };



  // Vendor fixes.
  $this
    .css('-ms-overflow-style', '-ms-autohiding-scrollbar')
    .css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling', 'touch');

  // Hide on click.
  if (config.hideOnClick) {

    $this.find('a')
      .css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

    $this
      .on('click', 'a', function(event) {

        var $a = $(this),
          href = $a.attr('href'),
          target = $a.attr('target');


        if (!href || href == '#' || href == '' || href == '#' + id)
          return;

        // Cancel original event.
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Hide panel.
        $this._hide();

        // Redirect to href.
        window.setTimeout(function() {

          if (target == '_blank')
            window.open(href);
          else
            window.location.href = href;

        }, config.delay + 10);

      });

  }

  // Event: Touch stuff.
  $this.on('touchstart', function(event) {

    $this.touchPosX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    $this.touchPosY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;

  })

  $this.on('touchmove', function(event) {

    if ($this.touchPosX === null ||
      $this.touchPosY === null)
      return;

    var diffX = $this.touchPosX - event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
      diffY = $this.touchPosY - event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,
      th = $this.outerHeight(),
      ts = ($this.get(0).scrollHeight - $this.scrollTop());

    // Hide on swipe?
    if (config.hideOnSwipe) {

      var result = false,
        boundary = 20,
        delta = 50;

      switch (config.side) {

        case 'left':
          result = (diffY < boundary && diffY > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffX > delta);
          break;

        case 'right':
          result = (diffY < boundary && diffY > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffX < (-1 * delta));
          break;

        case 'top':
          result = (diffX < boundary && diffX > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffY > delta);
          break;

        case 'bottom':
          result = (diffX < boundary && diffX > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffY < (-1 * delta));
          break;

        default:
          break;

      }

      if (result) {

        $this.touchPosX = null;
        $this.touchPosY = null;
        $this._hide();

        return false;

      }

    }

    // Prevent vertical scrolling past the top or bottom.
    if (($this.scrollTop() < 0 && diffY < 0) ||
      (ts > (th - 2) && ts < (th + 2) && diffY > 0)) {

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

    }

  });

  // Event: Prevent certain events inside the panel from bubbling.
  $this.on('click touchend touchstart touchmove', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Event: Hide panel if a child anchor tag pointing to its ID is clicked.
  $this.on('click', 'a[href="#' + id + '"]', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    config.target.removeClass(config.visibleClass);

  });

  // Body.

  // Event: Hide panel on body click/tap.
  $body.on('click touchend', function(event) {
    $this._hide(event);
  });

  // Event: Toggle.
  $body.on('click', 'a[href="#' + id + '"]', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    config.target.toggleClass(config.visibleClass);

  });

  // Window.

  // Event: Hide on ESC.
  if (config.hideOnEscape)
    $window.on('keydown', function(event) {

      if (event.keyCode == 27)
        $this._hide(event);

    });

  return $this;

};
```

Comment: That's what I thought - adding in the key but for some odd reason it doesn't work :(

Comment: My only guess is that the translation could be attempted before the cloning of the nav takes place.